# Why Won't My Inputs in a form with a Get method work together?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, get

Posted this one on the WordPress stack exchange site because I was working on a WordPress site, but I think it's a better question for here.

I have two inputs that I'd like to use as a part of the same form. Both of them deliver a $_GET to the url bar perfectly, but only when they're working alone. When both are on the page, entering a value for either one and pressing return will do nothing.

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="get">
  <?php
  /* receiveGET() is just a function I wrote that grabs the $_GET results */
  $inst = receiveGET(instrument_search);
  $search_field = receiveGET(user_search);

  /* all the form processing stuff goes here, and it's all working properly */
  ?>
  <!-- If this input is deleted, the other input works perfectly. -->
  <table id="musician-field" class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input title="Search User" name="user_search" maxlength="21" placeholder="Search Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[user_search]); ?>" ></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- If this input is deleted, the other input works perfectly. -->
  <table id="instrument-field" class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input title="Search Instrument" name="instrument_search" maxlength="21" placeholder="Search Instrument" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET[instrument_search]); ?>" ></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  /* The form close tab is way below a lot of PHP and HTML, 
  but I have the same bug happen when I move it up to be 
  directly enclosing the inputs */

  </form>
```

I know all the variables are going through properly, so I'm positive this is stemming from my poor understanding of how forms work, but I can't figure out what the problem is. None of the things I've seen online seem to put a limit on the number of inputs that go into a form. Anyone care to enlighten me and know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just spit balling but you could try changing your method to post and see if results are the same

Comment: I don't see a php closing tag `?>` after your php.. Could be messing with your form data

Comment: Hey Klynicol. I screwed up when I posted the question initially and forgot the PHP tag. Fixed. Thanks.

Also, I just tried it with POST and got the exact same result. =(

Answer (score 0):

Alright a couple of things.

1. I just tested your code and was getting an Undefined index error for `user_search` and `instrument_search`. So I tried doing an isset function before them and it worked for me.
2. You forgot to put the single quotes in `$_GET['user_search']` and `$_GET['instrument_search']`.

**Try the following code in your values:**

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['user_search']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['user_search']) : ' '; ?>
```

**and**

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['instrument_search']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['instrument_search']) : ' '; ?>
```

What is your purpose of using the value tag in the inputs anyway? You can use $_GET in your php and get the values without using a value tag. Using a `value=` is going to overwrite your placeholder and the input box will display no text upon loading the page!